# What does "+ complete" mean?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm reading notes about Liapunov stability, and in the book of Abraham, Marsden and Ratiu I found the next definition:

> Let $m$ be a critical point of $X$. Then 
>   $m$ is stable (or Liapunov stable) if for any neighborhood $U$ of $m$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $m$ such that if $m'$ $\in$ $V$, then $m'$ is $+$ complete and $F_{t}(m') \in U$ for all $t \geq 0$ .

I want to know what "$+$ complete means.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's defined a few pages earlier (2.1.13). It means that the integral curve starting at $m'$ at $t=0$ is defined for all $t>0$.